# Is there a better way to model this access pattern than to use two global secondary indexes (GSI)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index, amazon-dynamodb-data-modeling

I'm trying to figure out the data model and access patterns for an app keeping track of animal movements between different fields (pastures). There are movement records that look like this:

```
PK                 FROM            TO          DATE
------------------------------------------------------
ANIMAL#001       FIELD#A       FIELD#B       January 3
ANIMAL#001       FIELD#Q       FIELD#R       September 19
ANIMAL#002       FIELD#A       FIELD#B       January 3
ANIMAL#003       FIELD#C       FIELD#D       March 15
ANIMAL#005       FIELD#F       FIELD#A       April 22
```

For a specific field, *e.g.* `FIELD#A`, I'd like to know all the movements into and out of that field, the date of the movement, and the number of animals. The results should look like:

```
DATE        FROM        TO          NUMBER_ANIMALS
--------------------------------------------------
January 3   FIELD#A     FIELD#B         2
April 22    FIELD#F     FIELD#A         1
```

**Possible solutions and attempts:**

1. A GSI with `PK=FROM, SK=TO`. If I query the GSI with `PK=FIELD#A`, this only gives one half of the picture, that is, movements *from* `FIELD#A`. I can't obtain movements *to* `FIELD#A`.
2. A composite attribute like `FIELD#A#FIELD#B` used as the `PK` in a GSI. Runs into the same problem as attempt 1.
3. Two GSI. GSI1 has `PK=FROM` and GSI2 has `PK=TO`. I can query GSI1 with `PK=FIELD#A` and do some post-processing (`groupby, count`) to get part of the result. I can then query GSI2 with `PK=FIELD#A` and post-process, getting the rest of the result. This looks like it will work but requires two GSI and two queries. I can't overload one GSI since both columns in use are from the same item.
4. Some combination of scanning the entire table and filtering the results which I'd rather avoid since there might be 50,000+ items in the entire table.

I can see how to do it with two GSIs,  but what's the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could imagine a slightly different table structure (`ANIMALID` being the partition key and `FIELDID` being the sort key):

```
ANIMALID | FIELDID | FROM_TO | ...
——————————————————————————————————
ANIMAL#1 | FIELD#A | FROM    | ...
ANIMAL#1 | FIELD#B | TO      | ...
ANIMAL#2 | FIELD#C | FROM    | ...
ANIMAL#2 | FIELD#A | TO      | ...
```

And a GSI with the following structure:

```
FIELDID | ANIMALID | ...
```

Then you can query the GSI just by `FIELDID` and aggregate the results.